# 円グラフにアニメーションをつけたい。

Tags: objective-c

円グラフを作っているのですが、これを下図の左図から右図のようにグラフの値が変わるアニメーションを加えたいです。どのような方法がありますでしょうか。

グレーの部分のコード

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGFloat x = rect.origin.x;
x += rect.size.width/2;

CGFloat y = rect.origin.y;
y += rect.size.height/2;

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, x, y, x-10, 0, M_PI*2, NO);
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,0.6, 0.6, 0.6,1.0); //gray

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

円グラフは以下のサイトの方法を参考に作成しました。
http://qiita.com/rnsm504/items/1c9e71a318fc8bbd5ab8

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力][image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

`CALayer`のサブクラスとして実装し、暗黙のアニメーションに対応させるのが楽だと思います。

#### [アニメーションするグラフの実装例](https://gist.github.com/glayash/38aa605f99a9666a925d)

`Swift`練習兼ねてるので、`Swift`で申し訳ありませんがコード例です。雑です。

ただ`Objective-C`でもあまり変わらないと思います。

基本的にやることは以下の4点です。

1. アニメーションに利用する変数を、キー値コーディング互換（プロパティでOK）にする。
2. `-drawRect:`の描画処理を、`-drawInContext:`へ移植する。
3. `+needsDisplayForKey`でキーパス（プロパティ名）が渡されたとき、`YES`を返すようにする。
4. `-initWithLayer:`を実装する。このイニシャライザでは直前の状態のレイヤが渡されます。プロパティをコピーします。

#### アニメーションさせる方法

`CABasicAnimation`を利用します。

```
var graph = AnimatableGraph()
graph.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 200)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(graph)

var animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "degree")
// 10秒間
animation.duration = 10
animation.repeatCount = 1
// 9時の方向から時計回り1周
animation.fromValue = 0.0
animation.toValue = 360.0
// アニメーション完了後の状態に関するおまじない
animation.removedOnCompletion = false
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
graph.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "key")
```

ちょっと記述が煩雑なのが難ですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

class AnimatableGraph : CALayer {
    
    var degree: Double = 0.0 {
        didSet{
            if(degree < 0){
                self.degree = 0
            }else if(degree > 360){
                self.degree = 360.0
            }
        }
    }
    override init!(layer: AnyObject!) {
        if let layer = layer as? AnimatableGraph {
            degree = layer.degree
        }
        super.init(layer: layer)
        needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
        contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    }
 
この部分をobjective-cで表現する方法がわかりません

Answer (score 0):

わかりやすい方法として、以下の2つの方法があります。

1. 一定の間隔でUIViewのsetNeedsDisplay()を呼び出して、drawRect()の中で経過時間に応じたグラフを描画する
2. あらかじめ複数のUIImageを描画しておいて、UIImageViewの機能を使ってアニメーションさせる

1の方法を使うのであれば、CADisplayLinkについて調べるといいかもしれません。